# How can I get a user input and display it on a single page for my chat app

Tags: javascript, html, forms, chat, chatbot

I am working on a chat web app just like Whatsapp and I have created a form where users can type a  message but after doing that, I have a problem with making a users input display on a single page but it's displaying on a new page please how can I do that. I use the document.write()

I used a document.write() method but It's showing me what I am not expecting. What I need is to display input on a single page, not on another page

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` is old and even [strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/write). You should append a new element to part of your page.

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/createElement) would work well.